# How to wait firebase to loaded data before render page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have a function that getting data from firebase realtime database.
But It's seem like it's took some time so my parameter "doPosttest1" is always false and after a second, if found data "doPosttest1" will change but it too late.

How can I do async or wait until data loaded, then render the page?

Thank you.

PS. I'm using Ionic V.3

```
// Check posttest 1
let doPosttest1 = false;
var refPosttestSubject1 = this.db.database.ref("/testSubmit/Onboard-Safety-and-Security/posttest");
refPosttestSubject1.orderByChild("email").equalTo(this.auth.currentUser.email).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
  doPosttest1 = true;
  console.log(snapshot.key + " was " + snapshot.val().name + " meters tall");
});

this.isDoPosttest1 = doPosttest1;
```

Comment: did you try to also add the this.isDoPosttest1 = doPosttest1; line, between doPosttest1 = true; and the console.log... ?

Comment: yes, but it's doesn't know "this.isDoPostTest1". So i have to to like this.